# is tcpdump affected by iptables filtering?

Tags: linux, networking, linux-kernel, iptables, tcpdump

If my development machine has an `iptables` rule to `FORWARD` some packets, are those packets being captured by tcpdump? I have this question because I know there exist other chain called `INPUT` which filters packets to apps, if a packet is routed to `FORWARD` chain, will it reach `tcpdump` app?

May you make some reliable reference to official documentation or express well explained ideas to solve this question?

Comment: Not in my experience (and I have used quite some natting and filtering). Whatever _physically_ hits the network interface, tcpdump/tshark/wireshark will report it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TCPDump captures traffic from the hardware device. Iptables handles network frames at a different level.

So the answer is no, TCPDump will capture traffic only when it passes through the network card. IPtables can be taking inbound traffic on a card that TCPDump is monitoring, but may send it outbound on a different network card that is not being monitored by TCPDump.

Just remember, TCPDump will catch the traffic only if it passes through the network card.