# Is tcpdump 100% reliable on outgoing connection?

Tags: linux-kernel, tcpdump

I'm working on a server.
Its doing health check to another server, like a simple tcp open connection
Basically my tcpdump says that the packet (the health check tcp sYn packet) is going out of my interface.
But, the Firewall doesnt see anything.
I have doubt if the packet is going outside the server at all, or the problem is on the switch.
Is there a way to be sure about this?

Answer (score 0):

### Captured traffic == source of truth

It's possible for tcpdump to have false negatives (i.e. packets are sent but tcpdump doesn't record them). This can be due to hardware (CPU, RAM, disk) being maxed or if tcpdump's buffer size (`-B`) is too small. Likewise, it's possible your firewall isn't picking it up where it should.

It's highly unlikely for tcpdump to report a false positive. Tcpdump copies bytes from your network interface [0] and summarizes them in a text line (depending on your output options). If firewall rules from e.g. `iptables` would block traffic, tcpdump [won't see the traffic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43002164/is-tcpdump-affected-by-iptables-filtering). If tcpdump reports a packet, you can be sure it transited that interface.

[0]: If you're curious how tcpdump works at a lower level, use [strace](https://strace.io/).

### Flow-based troubleshooting

Flow-based troubleshooting can be required to figure out where packets get dropped in a network. For your network of `server:A <-> B:switch:C <-> D:Firewall`, we know that A sends it and D does not receive it. Thus you should check ports B and C to determine where the packet loss occurs. It's also possible that D reports a false negative. You can test both of these things by plugging this server directly into a different firewall that can take packet captures/monitor traffic.